# Scrape text after ::before (xpath, css)

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I have built a Scrapy Spider and would like to get the email text from:

::before
  "E-Mail"

"E-Mail I would like to scrape"

I've tried: 'email' : response.css('#content > div.segment.morecontact.clearfix > div > div.secondary > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a > i::text').extract(), but I'm only getting "E-Mail" and NOT the actual address

Comment: can you send the actual html snippet

Comment: Sure, maybe it's a stupid question but how exactly? Can I just take a photo of it and crop it? Thanks

Comment: https://adresse.dastelefonbuch.de/Paderborn/2-0222934641211-Sportbedarf-Bremer-Reitsport-Paderborn-Tegelweg.html

Comment: Here ist the direct Link, I need the email from the class icon.icon_email

Comment: can you highlight the part that you want to scrape and give me the screenshot . i will send you the xpath expression

Comment: I'm at work right now but I can do it later. Also, if you go to chrome selector tool and click on the email link, you'll see the class and the email text. Would that also work? Thanks

Comment: I will send you the snippet later as well. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You need a simple XPath's `following-sibling::*`:

```
email = response.xpath('//i[contains(@class, "icon_email")]/following-sibling::text()[1]').get()
```

You can use another approach and get email from `href` attribute:
    email = response.xpath('//a[i[contains(@class, "icon_email")]]/@href').re_first(r'mailto:(.+)')

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try it out later and write back! Thanks again

Comment: Hey, thanks it works, but now I see, some email text is under one another in span, so I only get the beginning part of the email text. Is there a way to concatenate the whole email text? example: 'in'
                                             'fo@'
                                             'some'
                                             'text'
                                             '.com'

With always a span class in between. Thanks AGAIN :)

Comment: https://adresse.dastelefonbuch.de/L%C3%BCbeck/2-Krankengymnastik-Hofmann-Hachmann-Physiotherapie-Ergotherapie-L%C3%BCbeck-Oberb%C3%BCssauer-Weg.html    Like this email, for example